# How to start OpenTelemetry GRPC collector without TLS?

Tags: open-telemetry-collector

How do I launch the OpenTelemetry Collector with GRPC, but without TLS. This is for local development where I don't want TLS.

Currently I'm using a config.yaml snippet like the below:

```
extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

service:
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging]
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: "debug"
```

Is something missing here, because I keep seeing error message as follows when I try to connect an exporter to it:

```
transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x01o\\x01\\x00\\x01k\\x03\\x03͙\\x19n\\xf1\\xa0k\\x18=>t\\x8a\\r\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS configuration for the OpenTelemetry collector can be added under the `tls` key of an exporter or receiver. Be default, TLS is enabled.

In your example, if you want to be able to send non-TLS telemetry data to the collector, you should update your receiver configuration to disable TLS:

```json
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        tls:
          insecure: true
      http:
        tls:
          insecure: true
```

Reference: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/v0.82.0/config/configtls/README.md#tls--mtls-configuration